# spritekit enemy dropping an item

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

it seems that i've been asking a lot of questions on here. i need to know now how to have a enemy drop an item after it is destroyed. i have it so when the player collides with the enemy, it will destroy the enemy, but i need it so when the enemy is destroyed it will spawn an item in its place.

heres the code for destroying the enemy:

```
func handleAttackButtonHover(isHovering : Bool) {
    if isHovering {
        attackButton.texture = attackButtonPressedTexture
        invincible = true
        print("invincible = true")
        playerNode?.removeAction(forKey:"animate")
        playerNode?.run(attackAnimation,completion:{
            self.playerNode?.run(self.animation,withKey: "animate")})
    } else {
        attackButton.texture = attackButtonTexture
        invincible = false
        print("invincible = false")
        playerNode?.removeAction(forKey:"attackAnimation")
        playerNode?.run(animation,completion:{
            self.playerNode?.run(self.animation,withKey: "animate")})
    }
}
```

and also:

```
//physicsbody for player and enemies  and coins
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //        var bodyA = SKPhysicsBody()
    //        var bodyB = SKPhysicsBody()
    //print("collision detected")
    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "player" || contact.bodyB.node?.name ==  "player" {
    //print("collision detected")
        if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "enemy" {
            if invincible == true {
                contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
            } else {
                contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
            }
        } else if contact.bodyB.node?.name == "enemy" {
            if invincible == true {
                contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
            } else {
                contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, what's the **specific** issue? Why the code dump?

Comment: i was showing how i have the destroying the enemy set up. what i was needing is that i don't know what code would be needed to make it so when the enemy is destroyed i would have an item spawn in there place

Comment: Have you tried anything to make it happen or are you simply copy-pasting code from the answers you get?

Answer (score 2):

I would attach the item to the enemy upon creation, then when it is destroyed, you can take the attached item, move it to the scene, and then kill the enemy off.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

   //You may want to think about doing integer base checks instead of string
   let player = (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "player") ?  contact.bodyA.node  : (contact.bodyB.node?.name == "player") ? contact.bodyB.node : nil
   let enemy = (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "enemy") ?  contact.bodyA.node  : (contact.bodyB.node?.name == "enemy") ? contact.bodyB.node : nil

   if player != nil && enemy != nil{

        if invincible == true {
            let item = player.childNodeWithName("item")
            item.move(toParent:self)
            item.isHidden = false
            player.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            let item = enemy.childNodeWithName("item")
            item.move(toParent:self)
            item.isHidden = false
            enemy.removeFromParent()
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function that takes in a CGPoint. The CGPoint is used to set the items position. Something like this

```
func spawnItem(point: CGPoint) {
    //create the skspritenode
    let item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin");
    //Set the item position to the position you passed into the function
    item.position = point
    //Set the name of the item
    item.name = "Coin"

    //set up physics if needed
    item.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(circleOfRadius: self.size.width / 2)
    item.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.coin
    item.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.player
    //And so on

    //Then add it to your scene
    self.addChild(item)
}
```

Then when you hit the enemy you call the spawn function passing in the enemy position.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //        var bodyA = SKPhysicsBody()
    //        var bodyB = SKPhysicsBody()
    //print("collision detected")
    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "player" || contact.bodyB.node?.name ==  "player" {
    //print("collision detected")
        if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "enemy" {
            if invincible == true {
                spawnItem(point: contact.bodyA.node!.position)
                contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
            } else {
                spawnItem(point: contact.bodyB.node!.position)
                contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
            }
        } else if contact.bodyB.node?.name == "enemy" {
            if invincible == true {
                spawnItem(point: contact.bodyB.node!.position)
                contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
            } else {
                spawnItem(point: contact.bodyA.node!.position)
                contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this gets you on the right track.